VSCode JSON JS Intellisense Autocomplete not showing
I'm following this tutorial to get a refresher on React
https://youtu.be/LDB4uaJ87e0?t=3676
And at this timestamp, the person us able to see autocomplete for an imported JSON object and the nested values within as you can see in the below screenshot. I don't see any relevant config files in the repo of the tutorial nor do I see it in the video in the person's file structure within the IDE.

When I try to do the same, I see no autocomplete options for the JSON. I've tried multiple things like checking Intellisense settings and what not, I don't know if this is related to a JSON Schema or not but in the tutorial I saw nothing about this nor do I see any Type related comments at the top like I have been suggested elsewhere. How can I get JSON Intellisense Autocomplete working like in this video?
The JSON file for reference is jobs.json and looks like this:
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Senior React Developer",
    "type": "Full-Time",
    "description": "We are seeking a talented Front-End Developer to join our team in Boston, MA. The ideal candidate will have strong skills in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, with experience working with modern JavaScript frameworks such as React or Angular.",
    "location": "Boston, MA",
    "salary": "$70K - $80K",
    "company": {
      "name": "NewTek Solutions",
      "description": "NewTek Solutions is a leading technology company specializing in web development and digital solutions. We pride ourselves on delivering high-quality products and services to our clients while fostering a collaborative and innovative work environment.",
      "contactEmail": "contact@teksolutions.com",
      "contactPhone": "555-555-5555"
    }
  }
]

As you can see, the autocomplete looks like this for me

